# How to add Html code snippet into every page using CQ5 service components

Tags: java, google-analytics, components, aem, google-tag-manager

To get google tag manager data we need to add code provided by google into each and every page.

I dont want to manually add the code to each and every page component in CQ,as numerous templates can be created and it becomes manual job.

Instead i want to add the HTML code into my page on every page load.

Can i achieve this using service component(java class).

If not please, provide any alternative to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accounting for recent posts, your requirement, if I may paraphrase, says, "I want Google Tag Manager code included in all pages automatically, except on the pages where the author doesn't want it."  In that case, your option is some form of component instance on every page, where the component's dialog.xml has a simple include GTM/don't include GTM checkbox.  Alternatively, you could use a page property or a CQ5 tag.  In any case, the author has to check the box or not.

Answer (score 0):

you should use inheritance to achive this.
usually we got a so called "abstract" or "base" template which is more or less extending the foundtion page template were every other template can get kind of global code snipplets from. 
You can put this "global" code into a seperate jsp within the abstract-template too and let people overwrite/disable that functionality in some of the extending templates (in case it is not needed in 100% of them) optionally too.
use this template in a way you would normally use the foundation components in every other template you are creating as resourceSuperType and there you go :-)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by chrysler you can use inheritance for this. Alternatively if you are very sure that you will need this google tag manager code in pretty much all the pages put the code in header/footer components assuming here that you are using header/footer in all the templates.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. i am aware of this form of implementation wherein you create a parent page template and then refer to it via sling:resourceSuperType in all the child templates.

But what i wanted to know is if there is any other alternative wherein i dont have to host this code on the template's component, and the user can decide which page he wants to get tracked or not, who might not have coding knowledge.

Comment: Please edit your original question to include this information about your requirements.